# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred: in Common Webservice method

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to make generic post method for API call.In my loadNew method I want to add normal dictionary inside resource object.Resource contains normal data which will pass from controller class.And dictionary is passed as body of request. but while encoding "***Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"*** showing. How do I use dictionary in it?

```
    struct Resource<T> {
            let url: URL
            let request: URLRequest
            let dictionary : [String:Any]
            let parse: (Data) -> T?

    }

   final class Webservice {

            //    MARK:- Generic

            func load<T>(resource: Resource<T>, completion: @escaping (T?) -> ()) {

                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resource.url) { data, response, error in

                    if let data = data {
                        //completion call should happen in main thread
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completion(resource.parse(data))
                        }
                    } else {
                        completion(nil)
                    }

                    }.resume()

            }


            func loadNew<T>(resource: Resource<T>, completion: @escaping (T?) -> ()) {

                var request = resource.request
                request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

                do {
                    //FIXIT: error is getting here
                    let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(resource.dictionary)
                    request.httpBody = jsonBody
                }catch{}

                let session = URLSession.shared

                session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

                    if let data = data {
                        //completion call should happen in main thread
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completion(resource.parse(data))
                        }
                    } else {
                        completion(nil)
                    }

                    }.resume()

            }

        }
```

This method is called inside my Login controller.I have also tried assign it directly to request object but same error is showing

```
        func APICall(){

            guard let url = URL(string: Constants.HostName.local + Constants.API.User_Login) else {
                return
            }

            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"


            let resources = Resource<LoginReponse>(url: url, request: request, dictionary: dict){
                data in
                let loginModel = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LoginReponse.self, from: data)

                return loginModel

            }
            //        var response = LoginReponse()

            Webservice().loadNew(resource: resources) {
                result in

                if let model = result {

                    print(model)
                }

            }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading, and may indicate you're using an older version of Xcode. In 11.4.1, the error is much more explicit:

> error: value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Encodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

The problem is that `[String: Any]` is not Encodable, because there's no way to encode "Any" (what should happen if you passed a UIViewController here? Or a CBPeripheral?)

Instead of a dictionary here, looking at your code I would expect you to pass an encodable object here. For example:

```
struct Resource<Value: Decodable, Parameters: Encodable> {
    let url: URL
    let request: URLRequest
    let parameters : Parameters?
    let parse: (Data) -> Value?
}

final class Webservice {

         func loadNew<Value, Parameters>(resource: Resource<Value, Parameters>, completion: @escaping (Value?) -> ()) {

             var request = resource.request
             request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            if let parameters = resource.parameters {
                request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)
            }

            // ...

     }
```

That said, I'd probably turn this system around a bit. If you want to have a `Request<T>` (parameterized on the thing it returns, and not on the parameters it takes to generate it), that's fine. You can pack a bit more into the struct. For example:

```
let baseURL = URL(string: "https://example.com/api/")!

struct Resource<Value> {
    let urlRequest: URLRequest
    let parse: (Data) -> Result<Value, Error>

    // Things you want as default for every request
    static func makeStandardURLRequest(url: URL) -> URLRequest {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        return request
    }
}

// It would be nice to have a default parser when you can, but you don't have to put that
// into Webservice. The Resource can handle it.
extension Resource where Value: Decodable {
    init(urlRequest: URLRequest) {
        self.init(urlRequest: urlRequest, parse: { data in
            Result { try JSONDecoder().decode(Value.self, from: data) }
        })
    }
}
```

And then Resources are smart about themselves:

```
struct LoginParameters: Encodable {
    let username: String
    let password: String
}

struct LoginResult: Decodable {
    let authToken: String
}

extension Resource where Value == LoginResult {
    static func login(parameters: LoginParameters) -> Resource {
        var urlRequest = makeStandardURLRequest(url: baseURL.appendingPathComponent("login"))
        urlRequest.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)
        return Resource(urlRequest: urlRequest)
    }
}
```

Of course that may get repeated a lot, so you can hoist it out:

```
extension Resource where Value: Decodable {
    static func makeStandardURLRequest<Parameters>(endpoint: String, parameters: Parameters) -> URLRequest
        where Parameters: Encodable {
            var urlRequest = makeStandardURLRequest(url: baseURL.appendingPathComponent(endpoint))
            urlRequest.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)
            return Resource(urlRequest: urlRequest)
    }
}
```

And then Login looks like:

```
extension Resource where Value == LoginResult {
    static func login(parameters: LoginParameters) -> Resource {
        return makeStandardURLRequest(endpoint: "login", parameters: parameters)
    }
}
```

The point is that you can pull duplicated code into extensions; you don't need to stick it in the Webservice, or add more generic.

With that, your `load` gets a bit simpler and much more flexible. It focuses just on the networking part. That means that it's easier to swap out with something else (like something for unit tests) without having to mock out a bunch of functionality.

```
func load<Value>(request: Resource<Value>, completion: @escaping (Result<Value, Error>) -> ()) {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request.urlRequest) { data, response, error in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let data = data {
                //completion call should happen in main thread
                completion(request.parse(data))
            } else if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else {
                fatalError("This really should be impossible, but you can construct an 'unexpected error' here.")
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

There's a lots of ways to do this; for another, see this [AltConf talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXwJg0QTlZE&list=PLljEvxF6pJBBSQXDRnQvACukLJGybS17O&index=13&t=0s).

Comment: you are legend! thanks for explanation about encodable and decodable parameters.